# Swift - 'when' operator (is if repetitive?)

Tags: if-statement, swift, concurrency, while-loop

In Swift, does `if` 'keep checking'. I.E. will its function be called when the variable is changed. I have the variable `playBegin` which gets changed halfway through my program. However, instead of directly implementing code in the change, the variable `playBegin` is set to 'true' and the code is carried out elsewhere. Essentially my question is: will `if` update and check to see the state of it's variable, or will I have to use something else?

To act like `when` in this statement:

```
when playBegin {
    // blahdeblah
}
```

What would be a good substitute for `when`? `playBegin` is normally `false`, but becomes `true` halfway through the program.

Comment: Do you not want to use while or do-while for some reason?

Comment: Why not use an observer?

Answer (score 1):

drewag's answer is correct.  Also if you want the code to always get executed at least once:

```
do {
    // blahdeblah
} while playBegin == true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to repeat until playBegin is no longer true, you can just do:

```
while playBegin == true {
    // blahdeblah
}
```

If you simply want it to execute once if playBegin is true, you would use an if statement:

```
if playBegin == true {
    // blahdeblah
}
```

Comment: playBegin is normally false, but it gets set to true.

Comment: @WilliamClark I'm not sure how that has any effect here or what you mean. You are going to have to be more specific with what you want. This code is only ever going to be run once unless you have it within a larger loop. The only time the value of playBegin will matter for this is when this line of code is run.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Anna Dickinson had a good idea: use an observer.

To do this, you would set up a class:

```
class SomeObserverClass
{
    var playBegin:Bool = false
        {
        willSet(playBegin) {
            println("About to set playBegin to \(playBegin)")
        }
        didSet {
            if playBegin == true  {
                // your code when playBegin == true
                println("playBegin set to  \(playBegin)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your AppDelegate file, above (outside) the AppDelegate class instantiate this class:

```
internal let someObserverClass:SomeObserverClass = SomeObserverClass()
```

Then in your code someplace if you say something like:

```
someObserverClass.playBegin = someBoolValue
```

the observer class code will be executed.

EDIT:

I'm not sure what you mean by "elaborate", but I'll try.

An observer property is a special kind of class property.  For example, if you had a class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    var someBool:Bool = false

    func someFunction()
    {
        ... some code ....
    }

    func someOtherFunction
    {
        ... some other code ....
    }
}
```

then someBool is a class property of SomeClass.

SomeClass's properties and methods could be accessible from any other class that has visibility of an instance of SomeClass.  e.g. if you created an instance of SomeClass in your AppDelegate file outside of (above) the AppDelegate class (so that it's visible to any class in your project) with:

```
internal let someClass:SomeClass = SomeClass()
```

then the value of the variable someBool could be changed from anywhere in your project with something like:

```
someClass.someBool = true.
```

or someFunction could be executed with:

```
someClass.someFunction()
```

OK, that's basic stuff.

Now with an observer, it's the same thing except when we declare the class property someBool, we also define some code we want to be executed anytime the property (variable) is changed. In the code below, the only change to SomeClass is that I've added this code.

```
class SomeClass
{
    var someBool:Bool = false
    { 
        willSet
        {
            println("someBool is about to be changed from \(someBool)")
        }
        didSet
        {
            if someBool == true  
            {
                // your code when someBool is true
                println("someBool set to  \(someBool)")
            }else{
                println("someBool set to  \(someBool)")
            }
        }
    }

    func someFunction()
    {
        ... some code ....
    }

    func someOtherFunction
    {
        ... some other code ....
    }
}
```

If then somewhere else in your project you write:

```
someClass.someBool = true
someClass.someBool = false
someClass.someBool = true
```

You'll get:

someBool is about to be changed from false

someBool set to  true

someBool is about to be changed from true

someBool set to  false

someBool is about to be changed from false

someBool set to  true

A variation of this is:

```
class SomeClass
{
    var someBool:Bool = false
    { 
        willSet(someBool)
        {
            println("someBool is about to be changed to \(someBool)")
        }
        didSet
        {
            if someBool == true  
            {
                // your code when someBool is true
                println("someBool set to  \(someBool)")
            }else{
                println("someBool set to  \(someBool)")
            }
        }
    }

    func someFunction()
    {
        ... some code ....
    }

    func someOtherFunction
    {
        ... some other code ....
    }
}
```

If then somewhere else in your project you write:

```
someClass.someBool = true
someClass.someBool = false
someClass.someBool = true
```

You'll get:

someBool is about to be changed to true

someBool set to  true

someBool is about to be changed to false

someBool set to  false

someBool is about to be changed to true

someBool set to  true

Another Variation of this could be:

```
class SomeClass
{
    var someBool:Bool = false
    { 
        willSet(newBool)
        {
            println("someBool is about to be changed from \(someBool) to \(newBool)")
        }
        didSet
        {
            if someBool == true  
            {
                // your code when someBool is true
                println("someBool set to  \(someBool)")
            }else{
                println("someBool set to  \(someBool)")
            }
        }
    }

    func someFunction()
    {
        ... some code ....
    }

    func someOtherFunction
    {
        ... some other code ....
    }
}
```

If then somewhere else in your project you write:

```
someClass.someBool = true
someClass.someBool = false
someClass.someBool = true
```

You would get:

someBool is about to be changed from false to true

someBool set to  true

someBool is about to be changed from true to false

someBool set to  false

someBool is about to be changed from false to true

someBool set to  true

No need for if, do or while statements.  The willSet and didSet code gets executed any time the class property (variable) is changed.

You don't need to implement both willSet and didSet.  You can leave either of them out if you want.

Also, the willSet and didSet code does not get executed during initialization of the class.

I think this comes closer to the intent of your "when" statement than anything else.

Comment: Please could you elaborate your answer for my variable playBegin. Thank you